# Determine whether $\sum \frac{1}{n^3 \ln(n^4+9)}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^3 \ln(n^4+9)},$$ I was thinking of using the limit comparison test with $1/n^3$?

Comment: And how did your thinking work for you?

Comment: How about just direct comparison? The summand is less than $1/n^3$.

Comment: so for direct comparison 1/n^3 is a p-series where p=3 and since p is greater than 1 it converges. Since 1/n^3 is greater than the given series the smaller series must also converge. Is this correct?

Comment: The series converges for any $1/n^s$ with $s>1$. In some point the logarithm is greater than 1 so the sum converges.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: it is clear  $$\ln{(n^4+9)}\ge 1$$

Comment: so for direct comparison 1/n^3 is a p-series where p=3 and since p is greater than 1 it converges. Since 1/n^3 is greater than the given series the smaller series must also converge. Is this correct?

Comment: yes,you are right

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $$0\lt\dfrac{1}{n^3\ln(n^4+9)}\le\dfrac{1}{n^3}$$